# Ansible playbooks to manage AKS cluster

Tags: ansible, namespaces, azure-aks

I have created a aks cluster from azure portal manually and trying to run few tasks like creating namespace etc from rhel 7 server using Ansible playbooks. (connected and able to run kubectl from rhel server)

which host value do I have to mention in the below playbook to work.

PLAYBOOK USED:

```
---
- hosts: x.x.x.x
  gather_facts: no
  become: yes
  tasks:
    - name: create name space
      k8s:
        name: testing
        api_version: v1
        kind: Namespace
        state: present
~
```

Providing the rhel local IP from where I connected to aks clsuter throws me error while running playbook.

```bash
[testadmin@ansiblemaster test-project]$ ansible-playbook namespace.yml
[WARNING]: provided hosts list is empty, only localhost is available. Note that the implicit localhost does not match 'all'
[WARNING]: Could not match supplied host pattern, ignoring: 20.219.84.38

PLAY [20.219.84.38] ************************************************************************************************************************************
skipping: no hosts matched

PLAY RECAP *********************************************************************************************************************************************
```